# RailsInstaller not completing install on OS X 10.6, not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and to web development in general. Yesterday I successfully installed Git, osx-gcc-installer, RVM and Ruby on my Mac OS X 10.6. To try to get Rails and everything else I need, I downloaded RailsInstaller for OS X 10.6 and apparently made it at least through the unpacking of files, but now I have the RailsInstaller Setup window hanging on my machine for over two hours. It has a message "Completing the RailsInstaller setup wizard"... "Setup has finished installing Railsinstaller on your computer." Clicking on Finish, Back, anything does absolutely nothing; the window just sits there. Clearly something is not working, and I'm not sure what to do. I checked the Rails install in the terminal and got the following message:

> $ rails --help
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in`activate'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
>       from /usr/bin/rails:18

I'm hesitant to start killing processes or restart my machine. Also wondering if I'm going to have to purge everything I've already installed and start over from scratch, and not sure how I would go about that.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And I've now received an error saying "The application RailsInstaller-1.0.4-osx.10.6 can't be opened. -1712".

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble running the installer as well.  It was not exactly the same issues you had.

Running the installer from the terminal as root worked much better for me.
The command would look something like this:
sudo ./RailsInstaller-1.0.4-osx-10.7.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-intel --mode text

If that does not work, you can get additional debugging diagnostics with the --debuglevel flag.